# Iteratively transform vectors to/from the basis of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

I have a $n \times n$ banded symmetric matrix $A$ with bandwidth $k \ll n$, so it is quite sparse. The matrix is diagonalizable, $A = V^T \Lambda V$. Generally, $A$ is not positive definite.

I need to transform $n$ vectors $z_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $i = 1, \dots, n,$ to or from the basis of eigenvectors of $A$, which essentially means calculating the matrix products $V^Tz_i$ and $Vz_i$.

The matrix $V$ is generally dense, so each of the $n$ multiplications asymptotically  takes $O(n^2)$, altogether $O(n^3)$. Is there a faster algorithm, e.g. some iterative method, that would make use of the sparsiness of $A$ and manage the task faster?

Thank you for your suggestions!